# Ubicación GPS en segundo plano con versión de android 7.0 en adelante

Tags: android, gps

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación de seguimiento, pero siempre el sistema operativo android me vota el servicio que he creado para la transmisión de posicionamiento.

como puedo hacer para que el sistema no me bote el servcio?

con esto inicio el servicio

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            //para versiones con android 7.0 o superior.
     startForegroundService(newIntent(frmLogin.this,serviceTracking.class));
                        } else {
                            startService(new Intent(frmLogin.this, serviceTracking.class));
                        }`

muchas gracias

Comment: ¿ a que te refieres con "bote el servicio"? ¿se muestra algo en el LogCat?

Comment: los servicios son los que se ejecutan en segundo plano, quiere decir que están funcionando sin abrir una aplicación https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es-419 por alguna razón en las versión 7.0 en adelante el servicio deja de funcionar y no me da ningún error. @Jorgesys,

Comment: Hola, podrias revisar este post https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits